# What is the main purpose of List.single property?

Tags: dart

Some days ago, I noticed that Dart's List class has the `single` property. Then, I read an official API document, and understood how this property works. This mean I know that `List.single` works as follows:

```
print(['a'].single);     // outputs 'a'
print(['a', 'b'].single) // throws StateError
```

But I cannot find any practical use case of the `single` property. Childish codes showed above make no sense in actual programming, of course.

What is the purpose of the property? Why does this property throw an Exception if a List contains two or more elements? Why is it not a boolean property which stands for whether a List has only single element? How do Dart Language developers think it is useful to include `List.single` in the core API?

If you have any knowledge about this, I would appreciate it very much if you give me a hand.

Comment: Mmmm... Testing? https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/80988a506bdf74d2e87bf0d7e1211d035c2e5624/dart/tests/corelib/iterable_single_test.dart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`single`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.Iterable#id_single) in case you expect an `Iterable` to only contain one element. Here is a real world example:
We have database connection that has `query` method to execute a SQL queries. The method returns the rows affected by the query. Now consider a query where you only expect exactly one line to be affected:

```dart
var row = databaseConnection.query('SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE id=5').single;
```

This gives a short way of failing in case no or more then one line are affected. Sure, one could also write:

```dart
var rows = databaseConnection.query('SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE id=5');

if (rows.length != 1) {
  throw new StateError('Something is wrong');
}

var row = rows.first;
```

But this is much longer. Alternatively you may want to `assert`.

As `List` implements `Iterable`, it also contains `single`. The [`single`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:async.Stream#id_single) getter is also useful for streams, if you expect exactly one element. Consider the same example as a `Stream` of rows:

```dart
databaseConnection.query('SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE id=5').single.then((row) {
  print('Process the row');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's very easy to understand. I had overlooked that it works as a shorthand for asserting extracted records.